# Docker containers high disk usage

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I'm running some docker images using docker-compose on a virtual machine.
When I start these containers, they use about 55MB:

```
# docker system df

TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          11        7         6.038GB   1.891GB (31%)
Containers      14        14        55.83MB   0B (0%)
Local Volumes   32        4         27.25MB   27.2MB (99%)
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

after about a week, I get some warning about low disk space on virtual machines and I found that those containers consuming about 122GB of disk space!

```
# docker system df

TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          11        7         6.038GB   1.891GB (31%)
Containers      18        0         122.2GB   122.2GB (100%)
Local Volumes   28        6         27.2MB    9.633MB (35%)
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

I face this problem many times till I found that and use `docker container prune` to remove them.

I use a local path for volumes in docker-compose and point that path to some disk that is on a different partition than root(`/`).
here is a sample of my docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  webapp:
    image: my-image
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "8m"
        max-file: "4"
    environment:
      TZ: Asia/Tehran
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/data:/var/webapp/data:Z
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - db

 db:
    image: postgres:11
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: database_name
      POSTGRES_USER: database_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: database_password
      TZ: 'Asia/Tehran'
      PGTZ: 'Asia/Tehran'
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/db/:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
```

Comment: Please do not provide code, output and/or error messages in images: in most cases it is not readable, it impairs search engines ability to index the content, it prevents people trying to help you to copy/paste content if needed, it uses (in best cases...) 1000 times more data volume (e.g. disk space to store, data transfers....) than the equivalent text in code/citation block... and above all, it is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Comment: thanks you for your comment, I fixed that